# Storing Value instead of array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, radio-button, storage

Storing radio button value in array (temporary storage). Created 10 set of question those 10 sets having 4  options for each. Now i am storing it in array to check how many radio buttons are checked and how many are correct.
Now the problem is currently having 10 question. As Database will be increase more question will be loaded.

So what to use another method or any other technologies for storing and checking them.

New to Codeigniter

Here is the code where I am storing (in controller) and redirecting it to model and then result view page

```
public function resultdisplay()
{
    $this->data['checks'] = array(
         'ques1' => $this->input->post('quizid1'),
         'ques2' => $this->input->post('quizid2'),
         'ques3' => $this->input->post('quizid3'),
         'ques4' => $this->input->post('quizid4'),
         'ques5' => $this->input->post('quizid5'),
         'ques6' => $this->input->post('quizid6'),
         'ques7' => $this->input->post('quizid7'),
         'ques8' => $this->input->post('quizid8'),
         'ques9' => $this->input->post('quizid9'),
         'ques10' => $this->input->post('quizid10'),
         'ques11' => $this->input->post('quizid11'),                 
);                  
    $this->load->model('quizmodel');
    $this->data['results'] = $this->quizmodel->getQueanswer();
    $this->load->view('result_display', $this->data);
}
```

Any other method, because it's not possible for writing code creating array every time for every new question and their radio button

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop. Your radio buttons would look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="question[1]['a']" value="a"> Question 1, option a<br>
<input type="radio" name="question[1]['b']" value="b"> Question 2, option b<br>
...
<input type="radio" name="question[2]['a']" value="a"> Question 2, option a<br>
<input type="radio" name="question[2]['b']" value="b"> Question 2, option b<br>
...
```

Since you mentioned pulling from a database, I assume you have a loop to print out the radio inputs.

Your FOR loop, to print out the HTML, would look something like this:

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { // number of questions
    for($y = "a"; $y <= "e"; $y++) { // number of options for that question
        echo '<input type="radio" name="question['.$x.'][\''.$y.'\']" value="'.$y.'"> Question '.$x.'<br>';
    }
}
```

In PHP, the loop is this:

```
foreach($this->input->post('question') as $index=>$resultArr) {
// if radio is selected, then $resultArr[0] is the letter option selected and will match the
// $index value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamic one use this I have taken for 10 as an example, you can increase dynamically.

```
<form action="/index.php/welcome/getResponse" method="POST">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){ ?>
    <div>
        <label><?php echo ($i+1)."."; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <?php for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){ ?>
            <?php echo chr(65+$j); ?><input type="radio" name="<?php echo 'n_'.$i; ?>" value="<?php echo chr(65+$j); ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

and in controller

```
public function getResponse(){
    $resp = array();
    for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++)
    {
        array_push($resp,$this->input->post('n_'.$i));  
    }
    print_r($resp);
}
```

Output (sample)

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => A [3] => B [4] => C [5] => A [6] => B [7] => C [8] => D [9] => B )
```